# How to Use EntityFramework with Asp.Net without using EntityDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I need to use EntityFramework with Asp.Net.

I've read the Tutorials given by Microsoft in [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-3)

In that tutorial I learned to use the EF with EntityDataSource. But I want to do DB those operations without using EntityDataSource instead I want to use c# code and I would like to follow some structure like,

1. Asp.Net WebSite(Front-end View and Process)
2. DataAccesslayer(Connection)
3. BusinessLogicLayer(DB Process)

I wish to create and use The models on my own, I don't want to just refer the datasource to the Gridview and it displays, I want to write codebehind operation with c#. . .

Somebody tell me where could I find examples for that or if anybody knows that means please answer me with little explanation(since I'm a beginner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly assign entity framework objects as data source. Look at this [article in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738469%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

-- edit --

Here is the more appropriate reference for you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43367/ADO-NET-Entity-Framework-as-Data-Access-Layer

Comment: in that example how to create those models i.e., order.SalesOrderDetails;

Comment: Your project must be having .edmx file there. You need to create dataContext object and then use that object to get data